Front end fails to turn symbol black after definition, how to fix and why is it happening?
I occasionally get issues where I'm doing a expensive calculation and the symbols I'm assigning the outputs to do not become black after assignment. The value is correctly updated, but the symbol remains blue. Is there a front end token I can use to refresh whatever the front end is using to keep track of this? The symbol remains blue if I enter it in a new cell manually or cope it. The only thing I've found to work is Removing the symbol with Remove and redefining it, but when this occurs for several symbols at once (all the newly defined symbols in a cell glitch when this occurs) this is tedious. Even if I set the symbols to a new value, they do not update their color.
How can I "refresh" this syntax highlighting? Why/how is this occurring?

Are you certain the kernel has not crashed? That’s certainly a cause for symbols to turn blue (and users, truth be told). Now if they were never black, and fail to change on assignment, that would be a different matter and I’m at a loss there.

@DanielLichtblau, I’ve seen this behavior too but very very rarely.  I’ve never been able to reliably duplicate it; without that I can’t file a coherent bug report. It tends to happen when I have 10+ notebooks open and sharing a kernel that has been running for several days.

@DanielLichtblau the kernel did not crash, if I attempt to index into it, or display it, it returns the correct data. It is purely (afaik) a visual thing. @CraigCarter yes that tends to be the case! although last time it happened with a young kernel (few minutes), albeit a lot of evaluation since kernel start. also several Dynamic things present.
